# how to get access to variable objects?

Tags: php

I have a question about access to object properties that will be used in a loop

I have an xml file withe a struture like this :

```
<labels>  
    <artiste01>  
        <label>Premiere image</label>  
        <label>Deuxieme image</label>  
    </artiste01>  
    <artiste02>  
        <label>Description 1</label>  
        <label>Description 2</label>  
    </artiste02>  
</labels>
```

I read the file :

```
$label_file = file_get_contents('label_file.xml'); 
$label_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($label_file);
```

Then I need to loop through any of the artistexx level.

`$label_xml->artiste01->label[$i]` works, but how can I reference the `artistexx` as a variable ?

Is this possible ?
I can't figure out how to code this.

```
$obj->loopid->label[$i]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `{}` to use a variable to get an object property.

Like this:

```
$a = '01';
echo $label_xml->{"artiste$a"}->label[0];
```

Or just use the variable as the property:

```
$a = 'artiste01';
echo $label_xml->$a->label[0];
```

Comment: "use the variable as the property" :
I thought I had had tried this - it works fine - thanks :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.  Don't you love when the answer is simple? :-)

Answer (score 0):

does this work?

```
<?php

$label_file = file_get_contents('pikachoose/label_file.xml');
$label_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($label_file);

foreach($label_xml->labels->children() as $artist)
{
  echo $artist->getName();
}

?>
```